# How to upload an image in angular as an API client?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using Angular as a client to a Rails backend. I'd like to have a form that can accept multipart upload data, and pass it to the server. But the only data I get on the files is:

```
{"webkitRelativePath"=>"",
 "lastModified"=>1424644319000,
 "lastModifiedDate"=>"2015-02-22T22:31:59.000Z",
 "name"=>"imgres.jpg",
 "type"=>"image/jpeg",
 "size"=>7521}
```

Shouldn't this contain something else? I need the actual binary data. How do I get this?

Comment: That's fine. I just haven't found an answer there. All of those seem to need CDN url. I want to pass the image binary blob to my server. Possible?

Answer (score 0):

there is a module on file upload called [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload) check it out

hope this help you..!